# Iterate over array and change a certain property using Immunity Helper for a Redux Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, immutability

I'm trying to learn Immunity Helper as I think it would help me with my Reducers but I can't figure out how to change a property in all the objects of an array.

Any help please, I been stuck for so long

https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

my initial state

```
outputList: [
  { propertyIWantToChange: 'some value1' },
  { propertyIWantToChange: 'some value2' },
  { propertyIWantToChange: 'some value3' }, etc
]
```

Reducer that does not work.  I feel like my syntax is just off a bit but I can't figure out which part.

```
case types.SOME_TYPE: {

  return update(state, {
    outputList: {
      propertyIWantToChange: {$set: action.value}
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to iterate over that array. If that list accepts `map` then something like this should work, I guess:

```
case types.SOME_TYPE: {
  const lst = state.outputList.map((el) => {
    return update(el, { propertyIwantToChange: {$set: action.value}}
  });

  return update(state, { outputList: {$set: lst}})
}
```

Comment: it worked!  i just added colons before the "{$set:" in your code,  ty